# Debugging Postgresql 9.3 with Eclipse CDT and GDB

Tags: c, eclipse, postgresql, debugging

i am from java background and have used debugger in eclipse(java).

i have installed postgresql 9.3 as stated in this link: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse

The debugger works fine for the server(which waits and accepts incoming client connections).

1. When i connect a client with: **$ psql test** .Does the server create a new thread for the client?
2. Is it possible to attach debugger and set breakpoints in parser.c or executor.c in postgresql source files so that i can analyse how postgresql queries are executed?

I have tried attaching debugger and set breakpoints in parser.c and executed some queries in the client.But it doesnt stop at the breakpoint.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i connect a client with: `$ psql test`, Does the server create a new thread for the client?

No. The server creates a new `postgres` (or, on Windows, `postgres.exe`) *process* that communicates with the postmaster and other processes via shared memory and signals. PostgreSQL uses a shared-nothing-by-default multiprocessing architecture rather than a shared-everything-by-default multithreading architecture.

> Is it possible to attach debugger and set breakpoints in parser.c or executor.c in postgresql source files so that i can analyse how postgresql queries are executed?

Yes, if your debugger can follow backend forks from the postmaster, or if you directly attach your debugger to the backend you wish to debug. The latter is more common unless you're debugging backend startup.

A typical workflow is:

- Connect with `psql`
- `SELECT pg_backend_pid()`
- Connect the debugger to that process ID
- Set breakpoints and watches as desired and resume execution
- In the same `psql` session, run the query you want to debug backend execution of
- Switch to the debugger when it traps and start debugging

This works on Linux with gdb and Windows with Visual Studio. Presumably it works with Eclipse too.

More at [the developer FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ).

---

It is *possible* to instead debug the postmaster and use gdb's multi-process debugging features with `follow-fork-mode`, `detach-on-fork`, `schedule-multiple` and `non-stop` options, but it's complicated to get right, noisy, and will be confusing if you're used to gdb's normal break behaviour. It's also a bit awkward because PostgreSQL uses signals that gdb also uses, so some hacks are required to work around that. See [a blog post I wrote on the topic earlier](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/processes-breakpoints-watchpoints-postgresql/).

I recommend keeping it simple and attaching using `pg_backend_pid`.